# Undefined Variable in function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Hello everyone I'm making a simple Database search and inside of the function it says a variable is not defined i have a feeling this is a simple fix but i can't seem to figure it out why i cant pass array to the view, any help is wanted my controller is below.

> ErrorException thrown with message "Undefined variable: array"
>   18 ErrorException in C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel\app\controllers\HomeController.php:24

```
<?php

 class HomeController extends BaseController {

public function showWelcome()
{
    return View::make('hello');
}

 public function getSearch(){
    $query = Input::get('query'); 
    $Validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),
        array(
            'query' => 'required| min:5 | max:50 '
            ));

    if($Validator->fails()){
        echo "Baddd";
    }
    else{
        $raw_results =  DB::table('students')->select('Name', 'Date' ,'Class')->where('Name', 'LIKE', "%$query%")->get();
        $array = json_decode(json_encode($raw_results), true);
    }
    return View::make('Student.Student', array('Results' => $array));
}
```

}

Comment: Please post the error message (with line number if possible) so we can locate the error better!

Comment: You only set `$array` if the validation passes. So I am guessing validation failed?

Comment: Sorry, but my error is at the return and it says undefined variable  array

Comment: validation failed is not my error its more i need to get to the page before it can validate anything and i cant see it

Comment: You could try declaring the variable `$array` at the top of your method, like right before you set `$query` declare `$array = array();`. That way regardless of what else happens in your method the variable exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Chris  I needed to Put $array as a empty array in the validator

```
   <?php

   class HomeController extends BaseController {

    public function showWelcome()
   {
      return View::make('hello');
   }

 public function getSearch(){
    $query = Input::get('query'); 
    $Validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),
        array(
            'query' => 'required| min:5 | max:50 '
            ));

    if($Validator->fails()){
        echo "Baddd";
        $array =  array();
    }
    else{
        $raw_results =  DB::table('students')->select('Name', 'Date' ,'Class')->where('Name', 'LIKE', "%$query%")->get();
        $array = json_decode(json_encode($raw_results), true);
    }
    return View::make('hello', array('Results' => $array));
}
}
```